# BASH - Run command for each line in output of previous command

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, operating-systems

All,
I am want to request all network services using:

```
 networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

I then want to run the below command for each line in produced from the above command:

```
networksetup -setautoproxyurl "A LINE FROM ABOVE" http://etc...
```

Adiitonally, I only want to issue the setautoproxyurl command for service with "Ethernet" or "Wi-Fi" in the name

```
 networksetup -listallnetworkservices | while read line; do networksetup -setautoproxy $line http://etc...
```

Comment: `man xargs`? (read the part about `-n` parameter)

Comment: So far I have: networksetup -listallnetworkservices | while read line; do networksetup -setautoproxy$line http://etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in `networksetup -listallnetworkservices`
do 
    networksetup -setautoproxyurl $line http://etc...
done
```

Comment: please edit your question, rather play 20 questions. Good luck.

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: Can you be more specific?